# How to organize frontend on Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, web-frontend

How to build ordinary frontend structure using Django (Python 3)? What should I do to place, for example, gulp, Bower, SASS, React.js here?

Answer (score 0):

For making basic front-end structure you can use html and css. But if you want to make your site attractive then you can use framework like Zurb Foundation or Boostrap.